# How to get family name of System family in Revit API?

Tags: c#, api, revit

I want to get a family name of "System family instance" such as wall, roof etc.

I know that how to get a family name of Family instance, but I cannot figure out if the element is "System Family instance".

Thanks.

(*Element e is the element that I picked.)

```
FamilyInstance finstance = e as FamilyInstance;
FamilySymbol ftype = finstance.Symbol;
string famname = ftype.FamilyName;
```

Please recommend the solution that is using the revit api.

Comment: what is a system family instance?

Comment: all the instances except family instance. such as Basic wall, Oval Duct etc.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [What's New in the Revit 2015 API](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2014/04/whats-new-in-the-revit-2015-api.html) and search for [ElementType API additions](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2014/04/whats-new-in-the-revit-2015-api.html#4.05):

> The new property `ElementType.FamilyName` contains the localised string describing the family in which this ElementType belongs. For family symbols, this will be the name of the associated Family. For system family types, this will be the name used to group related types, such as "Oval Duct" or "Curtain Wall".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I've tried this code but it does not work.

ElementType elementType = e.GetType();
string familyname = elementType.FamilyName;

However, I cannot figure out how to change Element e as ElementType if the element is system family. Can you show me short code for example?

Comment: Oh!! I got the solution!
 `ElementId eId = e.GetTypeId();
            ElementType elementType = (ElementType)doc.GetElement(eId) as ElementType;
            string familyName = elementType.FamilyName;`

Answer (score 0):

As @pooh mentioned in the comment, given an element you will need to call [Element.GetTypeId()](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2016/cc66ca8e-302e-f072-edca-d847bcf14c86.htm). Here is a slightly more readable and robust answer:

```
   public static string GetFamilyName(Element e)
   {
      var eId = e?.GetTypeId();
      if (eId == null)
        return "";
      var elementType = e.Document.GetElement(eId) as ElementType;
      return elementType?.FamilyName ?? "";
   }
```